# Geometric Intuition: a matrix multiplied by its transpose is symmetric positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

What is the geometric intuition behind $M^tM$ is symmetric positive semidefinite?

Comment: orthonormal basis of eigenvectors

Comment: @Max Could you elaborate on it more? I understand that symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors, and all eigenvalues of symmetric positive semidefinite matrix >=0.

Comment: You can simply plug in the Jordan normal form representation for $M$ end up with a simular one for $M^{t}M$. Alternatively you can use the fact that $\left<x,M^{t}My\right>=\left<Mx,My\right>$.